# How can i check if all charterers in a word are existing into the other one?

Tags: c++, arrays, substring

I'm trying to make a code that takes tow words from user and store them as arrays and check if the first word's **all** characters are already exists in the second word , if Yes then just output  Yes , if NO then output a NO .
Example :

***input :***

ENTER THE FIRST WORD :

> fos

ENTER THE SECOND WORD :

> stackoverflow

***output :***

> YES

my code is not even close to what i actually want , but i will put it down maybe it will explain what I`m trying to do .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    
    char N1[7];
    char N2[10];
    cout <<  ("ENTER THE FIRST WORD : ") ;
    cin >> N1;
    cout <<("ENTER THE SECOND WORD : ");
    cin >> N2;
    for (int i = 0; i <4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
        {
            if (N1[i] = N2[j]) 
            {
                cout << ("YES") << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << ("NO") << endl;
            }

        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Tip: `unordered_map<string,int>`. Also, avoid `using namespace std;`.

Comment: `N1[i] = N2[j]` is an assignment, not a comparison. Also, C++ has `std::string`, no need for awkward char arrays. Also, `std::string` has `std::string::find`, which makes your task easier. Also you should really separate processes you can name into a function, in this case something like `bool contains_letters(const string& a, const string& b);`.

Comment: The key concept you are missing is that you can't decide **immediately** if your condition is true. You can only know at the end of your loops whether every item from the first string is in the second string. Whenever you have a problem that says 'all' you can use a boolean variable. Set the variable to true and then write a loop that tests each item. If **any** of them fail then set the boolean variable to false. To put it another way, assume you condition is true and first and then look for a single counter example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried it with simple search and 1 boolean variable to track if it is found or not.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;



int main()
{
string s1  = "fosq";
string s2 = "stackoverflow"; 
  bool isfound;
  for(int i=0;i<s1.length();i++)
  {
    isfound=false;
    for(int j=0;j<s2.length();j++)
    {
      if(s1[i]==s2[j])
      {
        isfound=true;
        break;
      }
    } 
      if(!isfound)
      {
        cout<<"Not found";
        break;
      }
  }
  if(isfound)
  {
    cout<<"Yes\n";
  }
}
```

Here what I am doing is that I am looping over both strings, comparing each element. If we can not find any element, I just break the search there, if we find all the elements, we simply just output Yes.

Comment: I have set values of `s1` and `s2` manually, you can ask for input via `cin`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not c++ expert but look like you want to check if **all** char are in the second string - so you better add booleans to your code as:

```
for (int i = 0; i <4; i++) {
    bool charFound = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        charFound = charFound || (N1[i] == N2[j]); // use OR operator so if found one match it is will stay true
    }
    if (!charFound) {
        cout << ("NO") << endl;
        return; // one char is missing - print no and exit
    }
}
cout << ("YES") << endl; // if got here you found all char - YES
```

Also notice the `==` instead of the `=` in your code (`N1[i] == N2[j]`) as in Aziuth's comments

Answer (score 1):

I think the most efficient way is to sort the two arrays before computing the match:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

template <typename T1, typename T2>
bool match(T1& arr1, T2& arr2) {
    for (char c2: arr2) {
        for (char c1: arr1) {
            if (!c1 || !c2) continue;
            if (c1 == c2) break;
            if (c1 > c2) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
int main() {
    std::array<char, 14> arr1 {"stackoverflow"};
    std::array<char, 4> arr2 {"fos"};

    std::sort(arr1.begin(), arr1.end());
    std::sort(arr2.begin(), arr2.end());
    
    if (match(arr1, arr2)) {
        std::cout << "YES" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "NO" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```